# Can I pin more solutions with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Perhaps this belongs on SuperUser, but I figured I might be more likely to get an answer here.  The company I work for has a very large codebase which is split up into a large number of solutions.  It's not uncommon for me to be working on 6 or 7 different solutions at one time.  In order to save myself some time when needing to open solutions to work on, I've pinned quite a few to the VS2010 taskbar menu.  Unfortunately I'm fast approaching the limit, which appears to be 15.  Does anybody know whether it's possible to change a setting or registry key somewhere to pin more than 15?

Comment: You might want to have a look at answer: http://superuser.com/questions/200153/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-the-pinned-jump-list-in-windows-7/262388#262388

Comment: A good question, but no point leaving it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of this being closed, I'm going to post the solution here anyway.  This comes from the SuperUser question referenced by tomlog above.  Edit this registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ApplicationDestinations\MaxEntries
```

I'm not sure how high you can set it, but I've got it at 25 right now.

**EDIT**

Turns out this isn't a perfect solution, as it appears to reset itself periodically with no pattern that I've been able to pin down just yet.  I've had to go back in and reset it to 25 a couple of times and it has always set itself back sooner or later.  If I figure out why I'll post more details.

Still no idea why this arbitrarily gets reset, but I've created a .reg to set it back where I want it when it does:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ApplicationDestinations]
"MaxEntries"=dword:00000019
```

If you choose to use it you can change the hex value to whatever you want it to be.